# Want to insert multiple value in column of SQL table separated by Comma ,

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add multiple UCId s in single column of SQL Server. I am using `Stuff` but result is showing all the UC id instead of condition.

Table:

```
UCId    UCPre                           UCPost                          UCNext (No column name)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UC01    User must be Registerd          User is Loggined sucessfully    UC02    UC03,UC05,UC02
UC02    User is Loggined sucessfully    User is added                   UC03    UC03,UC05,UC02
UC03    File must be selected           File is added                   NULL    UC03,UC05,UC02
UC04    File is added                   File is deleted                 NULL    UC03,UC05,UC02
UC05    User is Loggined sucessfully    User is deleted                 NULL    UC03,UC05,UC02
```

I am using following query:

```
SELECT 
    b.*,
    STUFF(
          (SELECT ',' + a.UCId 
           FROM UCDetails a, test b 
           WHERE (b.UCPost = a.UCPre)
           FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 
FROM 
    test b 
JOIN
    UCDetails a ON b.UCPost = a.UCPre
```

What I want:

I want in `UCNext` column of UC01 Id of UC02 and UC05 separated by commas (`UC02,UC05`) as the UCPost of UC01 is matched with UCPre of UC02 and UC05.

Comment: For the given data, could you post what exactly the new column values should be for each `UCid`?

Comment: Dear for UC01 the values for UCId in UCNext will be UC02 and UC05

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also discouraged: storing comma multiple values in a single column. Can there be more than two UC's stored in this column? You should create a new table which defines this link in two rows. It's a very bad idea to try and stuff multiple pieces of data in one column

Comment: Yes dear i know that .Kindly help me to solve the problem I mention above

Comment: How can I link the two rows in two seperate tabel

Answer (score 0):

Create a third table, possibly called `NextUCId` with two columns:

UCId and UCNext

The same UCId will be listed once for each NextUCId like this:

```
UCId | UCNext
UC01 | UC02
UC01 | UC03
```

Then you can do a join on this third table to get the UCNext ID's you need for the UCId, something like this:

```
SELECT     uc.UCId,
           nuc.UCNext
FROM       UCId uc
INNER JOIN NextUCId nuc ON (uc.UCId = nuc.UCNext)
ORDER BY   nuc.UCNext ASC
```

Comment: Dear thanks but I have to enter UCId in UCNext column on the base of UCPost and UCPre